# Using For Loop with JSON

Tags: json, for-loop

I have a JSON object below and there are multiple nested divisions, the first without any identifiers. I am trying to get to the teams within the last divisions using a for loop, but I am not able to access them. Need some guidance.

```
{
    "division": {
        "division": [
            {
                "team": {
                    "id": "229525",
                    "name": "MyTeam",
                    "photo": "",
                    "visible": "True",
                    "RosterView": "True",
                    "PublicResults": "True",
                    "Statistics": "False",
                    "privilege": [
                        "False",
                        "True",
                        "True",
                        "True",
                        "True",
                        "True",
                        "True"
                    ]
                },
                "name": "Boys 9-10",
                "id": "12897",
                "sort": "0",
                "open": "0"
            },
            {
                "team": [
                    {
                        "id": "229523",
                        "name": "Cougars",
                        "photo": "",
                        "visible": "True",
                        "RosterView": "True",
                        "PublicResults": "True",
                        "Statistics": "False",
                        "privilege": [
                            "False",
                            "True",
                            "True",
                            "True",
                            "True",
                            "True",
                            "True"
                        ]
                    },
```

Comment: you mean in javascript ?

Comment: Yes, it would help a little to know what language.  And see elsewhere for my "peel the onion" speech -- just take it one step at a time, using NSLog after each layer is removed to see what's next.  You've got to find "division" twice, then you've got an array of "objects", each "object" apparently corresponding to a "team".  But you've garbled the JSON somewhere since the first "team" is an "object" and the second is an array.

Comment: Hint: Go to json.org.

Comment: The json is returned from a web service. I'm using a js for loop to search through the nodes, but can't figure out how to get to the teams. Example, 'for (i=0; i<=JSONObject.division.division.teams[i].length; i++){}'. I know this isn't right, so just need some help.

Comment: There are too many keys and arrays in this json. If you just want to reach team object you dont have to use for loop. you can reach it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Hmmm, after reading your JSON carefully, I notice that the 1st division has only 1 team since the team has only one object. But seems like the 2nd division has more than 1 team since there is an array of objects in team. I guess you have to handle the case where there only one team in a division.

Your for loop was almost right. Try this:

```
var divisions = JSONObject.division.division;

for (var i=0; i < divisions.length; i++) {
    // handle division of one team here,
    // don't need for loop if there only one team
    // just do division[i].team.id
    for (var j=0; j < divisions[i].length; j++) {
        var teamId = divisions[i].team[j].id;
        alert(teamId);
    }
}
```

Your loop was

```
for (i=0; i <= JSONObject.division.division.teams[i].length; i++) { }
```

It has 2 problems, first you are skipping the last element by doing `i <= ...length; i++`
second, `JSONObject.division.division.teams[i]` is not an array, but this one `JSONObject.division.division[i].team` will give you an array of all the teams in a division. Then you can just get the team you want by its index in the array :)

Comment: It is sometimes the case that JSON will be constructed with on object if there is only one, but with an array containing objects for more than one.  This of course means the the form of the data must be tested before accessing.

Answer (score 1):

First you should fix your parenthesis in json.

```
var a = {
    "division": {
        "division": [
            {
                "team": {
                    "id": "229525",
                    "name": "MyTeam",
                    "photo": "",
                    "visible": "True",
                    "RosterView": "True",
                    "PublicResults": "True",
                    "Statistics": "False",
                    "privilege": [
                        "False",
                        "True",
                        "True",
                        "True",
                        "True",
                        "True",
                        "True"
                    ]
                },
                "name": "Boys 9-10",
                "id": "12897",
                "sort": "0",
                "open": "0"
            },
            {
                "team": [
                    {
                        "id": "229523",
                        "name": "Cougars",
                        "photo": "",
                        "visible": "True",
                        "RosterView": "True",
                        "PublicResults": "True",
                        "Statistics": "False",
                        "privilege": [
                            "False",
                            "True",
                            "True",
                            "True",
                            "True",
                            "True",
                            "True"
                        ]
                    }
                   ]
           }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then you can reach second 'team' object with:

```
a['division']['division'][1]['team'][0]['id'];
```

This will give you `id`. You can select anything you want. It is not so complicated. Just read it like a puzzle.

*Here is live example:* [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLSRm/)

**here are some for loops :**

```
var json1 = a['division']['division'][1]['team'][0]; // this is for second team array,
    json2 = a['division']['division'][0]['team']; // this is for first team object,

for (obj in json1){
    return json[obj];
};
```

According to your json, first and second `teams` are not in same data type.  first team is array but second one is object. Thats why there are two different variables.